# Pg_restore gives no errors in terminal, but doesn't seem to change anything

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm having problems using pg_restore to while creating new DB for testing purposes.

What I did:

- I've taken dump file created with `pg_dump oldDB -f /some/directory/oldDUMP.dmp` from my daily backup
- I've logged to postgres user and created new DB with `createdb -T template0 newDB`
- then I've tried to use (while being in the folder with my oldDUMP.dmp file) `pg_restore -d newDB oldDUMP.dmp` but output told me, that since dump is in txt, then I should log in to psql
- I logged in as postgres (`psql`) and typed `pg_restore -d newDB oldDUMP.dmp` again. Nothing showed up (seemed like it worked) but there is no differences - test database is still empty.

I've tried to do the same from other user, and tried to log to psql to newDB (since as I understand sole `psql` command logged to postgres because I was logged as postgres on Linux) and still there were no differences. I'm not sure where to look for, for some logs with possible errors.
I've been worried I somehow overwrited some old DB, but I doubt that's possible.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
I'm new to Postgresql/psql (and Linux), so it's probably some very basic problem, but I wasn't able to find such problem in Web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *but output told me, that since dump is in txt, then I should log in to psql*

You need to give psql the script as an input. Something like this:

```
psql < oldDUMP.dmp
```

> *I logged in as postgres (psql) and typed pg_restore -d newDB oldDUMP.dmp again. Nothing showed up (seemed like it worked) but there is no differences*

Did you type `pg_restore` in the psql prompt? That's the wrong place. `pg_restore` is a program, not a SQL statement. The reason why nothing happened is probably because you forgot to terminate the statement with a `;` - if you do that you will get a SQL syntax error.

Comment: Makes sense. The exact command that worked for me was:
`psql < oldDUMP.dmp newDB`
Of course as I understand command without newDB would have worked if I was logged to newDB user in terminal.
Anyway thanks for Your help once again. No idea why there was no error in output when I tried to use pg_restore in psql prompt though.

Comment: @hisu: as I said: if you forget the final `;` psql will just wait for you to complete the statement.

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand now. Missed that. Thanks for answers.